How to disable floating point exceptions in C/C++ code?
In my C or C++ code I want division by 0 to result in a float value +Infinity or -Infinity, calling sqrt(-1) or log(0) to produce a float value of NaN, etc. per the IEE754 spec.  The current behavior I see when any of these things happen is a floating point exception.  It is out of the scope of my program to catch exceptions, as it is performing a large number of operations and then performing an aggregate function, so if even a single NaN or infinity it must "poison" the results and make it an infinity or not-a-number.
I mention C and C++ because there is some interoperability, e.g. a C function compiled to a shared object library that may perform the floating point operation but get called from C++.
I originally was able to write some C code and it seemed the default was to NOT throw an exception.  However, this was throwaway code to test what the behavior was and unfortunately I did not save it.  Now when I try it I am not able to get back to the point where I can get a NaN into a float and then print it, instead I get an exception.
In C++ I am using:
#include <cfenv>

then in my code before I call the function that may generate an infinity or NaN I do this:
std::fenv_t envp;
// Clear all floating-point exceptions (not strictly necessary?)
std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
// save floating point environment and then don't generate exceptions
std::feholdexcept(&envp);

// Disable all floating-point exceptions (just for good measure)
fedisableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);

I am compiling this  using g++ with these flags:
-fno-trapping-math -fno-signaling-nans

In C I am using a similar approach:
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main() {
    fenv_t envp;
    printf("debug0:%d\n",feholdexcept(&envp));
    printf("debug1:%f\n",1/0);
}

note: I tried the pragma in my C++ code but g++ did not recognize the pragma.
gcc -fno-trapping-math -fno-signaling-nans -o test test.c -lm

gcc version is 6.3, g++ version is 6.5 (I don't have the option for a newer version at the moment as these are running on production systems.)

C does not throw exceptions (except possibly for integer divide by zero).

IIRC division by zero does not throw exceptions. You probably got a system interruption instead (SIGFPE)

@Fareanor is what I meant, you'd have to intercept the interrupt, on MSVC the code typically hangs.

How to prevent all floating-point exceptions in Visual C++?

@WeatherVane: Re “C does not throw exceptions (except possibly for integer divide by zero)”: C++ exceptions and floating-point exceptions are different things. The C standard does allow floating-point exceptions and allows them to trap.

1/0 is not floating point. That's integer arithmetic, and it can't produce infinity ... Did you mean 1.0/0?

@ChrisMM good catch... the library code is a bit more complicated but I think a cast to float may be missing in a spot...

You should rephrase your question. In floating-point, an exception is “An event that occurs when an operation on some particular operands has no outcome suitable for every reasonable application” (IEEE-754 2019 clause 2.1). For example, dividing 1 by 3 generates an inexact exception. The event here is that this condition occurs. That does not mean a trap is performed. There is nothing you can do to prevent an exception; it is a characteristic of the operation. What you seem to want to prevent is traps; you want execution to continue without stopping or trapping.

Integer division by zero can result in SIGFPE at least on Linux, but that's beyond the scope of the language standards. You can't suppress that SIGFPE with functions from <fenv>, and you can't get that to result in inf instead

The expression 1/0 is triggering an exception because you're doing division by zero with integers.  There's no floating point type involved here.
Where the division by zero is happening in your actual code must be done with floating point types in order for the result generate an INF value.

ah, indeed... that was just a test but it appears that the actual calculation is using a data structure that does have an integer in a spot that should be cast to float before performing the calculation.

@Michael integer in a spot that should be cast to float can lose precision with a float cast.  Better as "integer in a spot that should be cast to double".  If the integer is wide like long long instead of int, additional code needed.
